# Restore table from file raises errors

Tags: string, lua, load, lua-table

I'm saving a table with mixed values (no userdata) to a file.
When I'm trying to restore the table from that file, I get "unexpectet symbol near '{'"-Errors.

**Here's an example:**

```
eTable = {}
eTable.[1] = { [1] = 2, [2] = 3}
eTable.[2] = { [1] = 2, [2] = 9}
eTable.x = { [1] = 12, [31] = "aString", ["wildcard"] = function()something end}

local eTable_as_String = table.tostring(eTable)
local file_hanlder,err = io.open(filename,"w+")
if err then print(err) end -- doesn't raise errors
err = nil

file_hanlder:write(eTable_as_String)
file_handler:flush()
```

**Now the critical Part:**

```
loadet_eTable = loadfile(filename) -- "unexpectet Symbol near '{'"

loadet_eTable = dofile(filename) -- "unexpectet Symbol near '{'"
```

**other try:**

```
loadet_file_value,err = file_handler:read()
if err then print(err) end  -- doesn't raise errors
err = nil
loadet_eTable = loadstring(loadet_file_value) -- "unexpectet Symbol near '{'"
```

I know the difference between loadfile() and dofile(), it's not an issue in this case. But I don't understand, how this error occurs.

Comment: Are you sure the table you write to the file is correct? `table.tostring` is not a standard function, you should post the table in the file if you are sure the problem is in the `loadfile` part.

Comment: The string in file is:{[1] = { [1] = 2, [2] = 3},[2] = { [1] = 2, [2] = 9},x = { [1] = 12, [31] = "aString", ["wildcard"] = function()something end}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only wrote the content of the table to the file. As a simpler example,

```
{[1] = "foo", [2] = "bar"}
```

is not valid Lua code, you can add `return` in front of the table constructor to return the table like this:

```
return {[1] = "foo", [2] = "bar"}
```

Now if it's loaded and run successfully, the table is already there:

```
local fun = assert(loadfile(filename))
local t = fun()
```

Comment: locals don't show up in other chunks, so you should make `t` a global variable (or use `return` to pass the table through `dofile`).

Comment: @siffiejoe Using `return` is better, I'll modify the answer. But I don't see the use of `local` a problem as it could be used in the same chunk.